# Uninitialized pointer object with inheritance

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization, undefined-behavior

I am using an uninitialised pointer object to access the member function. It works and I know how it works. But when I derived that class with B and tried to access that member function, it gives segmentation fault. Can someone please explain why it shows two different behavior?

Following is the program:
If I comment line 29, it works but without that it fails.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    int no;
public:
void printml(int i)
    {
        no = i;
        cout << "in base: value"<<no;

    }
 };
class B:public A
    {
        public:
        void printdl()
        {
            cout << "in derived" ;
        }
    };

int main()
{
    A *ptr;
    B *ptr1;
    ptr->printml(1);
    ptr1->printml(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **"It works and I know how it works"**.. Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Sorry,It was typo. it will crash in that case also but it will work if we don't use member variable inside the called function. Because in that case this pointer will not be dereferenced. That's why it will work. But in the ABOVE PROGRAM, we are using member variable, so it will crash.

Answer (score 4):

Dereferencing an uninitialised pointer is *undefined behaviour*. Why do you think it shouldn't crash?

Comment: then why it is working in first case(without inheriting) and after commenting the line 29.

Comment: Undefined behaviour means the behaviour is *not predictable*. So it might crash, or it might not, but your code is still broken either way.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will most likely produce a segmentation fault the first time you use the dereference operator (`->`) on an uninitialised pointer or a null pointer. It is undefined behaviour. That means if it worked for you, that's mere luck, or rather bad luck, because you were misleaded by the compiler looking for an error.

Use pointers like this:

```
A *ptr = new A();
ptr->printml(1);
```

Comment: Thanks, I know this but my question is why it is not producing segmentation fault when we comment "ptr->printml(1);" and dereference another uninitialize derived object to access member function.

Answer (score 0):

When you call function following thing happens
1) Compiler checks type of object (not content) and calls the member function of that type.
2) It passes this pointer (pointer pointing to object itself) as first parameter to the member function
3) it implicitly uses this pointer to call member variables.

Considering above points, In your case, when you are not using member variable inside the member function this pointer is not used that's why it does not crashing and when you use member variable it crashes.

Still this is considered as undefined behavior and one must not use pointer object without initializing it.